# PHP: date value not working. Is it different depending on version of PHP?

Tags: php, date

I have some code that was working fine for the last couple years. Then my host changed my version of PHP and when that caused some problems, at my request changed it back again.  Ever since, I have noticed some odd things happening.

One is that the YEAR value in dates formatted as follows are now displaying as -1 instead of 2015.  It still displays fine if the year is 2013.

Has anyone observed this before and/or can suggest a fix.

Here is code:

```
function fulldate($datetime) {
$fullDate = strtotime($datetime);
$fullDate = date("l F jS, o",$fullDate); // o and Y both display as -1
return $fullDate;
}
```

Edit:

if `$datetime` = 2015-10-20 14:30:00, then the year displays as -1

Comment: what valuea re you passing in for `$datetime`?

Comment: I agree with Marc; do an echo $datetime on the top of that function and let us know..

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a dig on the php `date` man page:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

For the letter `o` in your format:

> ISO-8601 year number. This has the same value as Y, except that if the ISO week number (W) belongs to the previous or next year, that year is used instead. (added in PHP 5.1.0)

Maybe it could be that that function is missing?

You don't say what the version was before or after, thats worth finding out definately.

Edit: you cant put Y in cause it doesnt work, just read your comment.

Comment: According to my host the current version is 5.3.  They say that was the version before, however, I have noticed a few things that are out of whack.

Comment: What things are? Cause when I use your function in my development environment I get "Tuesday October 20th, 2015" like supposed

Comment: Things other than this such as errors in uploading.  The error here is -1 as stated above instead of 2015.  I appreciate your trying it out yourself.